# dll load error specified module not found

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I installed `numpy` and `tensorflow` using Anaconda. However, anytime I try to import any of them I receive an error which says:  `dll load failed`

I have tried it on VSCode and PyCharm. I also tried installing everything over again. I tried copying the long path given by Anaconda to my system environment variable but nothing seems to be working and I keep getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "c:/Users/AYERHAN MSUGHTER/Desktop/Anaconda 3/test.py", line 1, in <module>    
        import numpy as np  
    File "C:\Users\AYERHAN MSUGHTER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\machinenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
        from . import _distributor_init  
    File "C:\Users\AYERHAN MSUGHTER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\machinenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
        from . import _mklinitImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
PS C:\Users\AYERHAN MSUGHTER\Desktop\Anaconda 3>
```

Comment: you used the anaconda prompt and typed ```conda install numpy```? and then called ```import numpy as np```?

Comment: I went straight to the anaconda navigator,created an enviroment and installed numpy

Comment: can you check your list of environments in the anaconda navigator just to be sure?